# iOS: define and use C++ in Objective-C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, poco-libraries

Can anyone tell me on how to define and use [BinaryWriter](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/blob/master/libs/poco/include/Poco/BinaryWriter.h) and [BinaryReader](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/blob/master/libs/poco/include/Poco/BinaryReader.h) ([from OpenFrameworks project on GitHub](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks)) C++ classes in iOS 5.x -> Objective-C++ ?

what i do:

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Poco/BinaryWriter.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{
    Poco::BinaryWriter *_myBinaryWriter;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

AppDelegate.mm

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    _myBinaryWriter = new Poco::BinaryWriter(NULL, NULL);

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

but in mm file i have compilation error:

> No matching constructor for initialization of 'Poco::BinaryWriter'

What is wrong and whar to do?

p.s. path to Headers of OpenFrameworks is configured in setting of project and linker can see Poco classes.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poco::BinaryWriter(NULL, NULL) there are no constructors with that signature in BinaryWriter.h, and you cannot convert from NULL to std::ostream&.

To test the BinaryWriter with the standard output (std::cout):

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#include <iostream>

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Only for testing
    _myBinaryWriter = new Poco::BinaryWriter(std::cout);
    (*_myBinaryWriter) << 1 << 3.14f;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Once you confirm that this is indeed working you can move on to actually using other std::ostream derived classes such as std::ofstream (output file stream).

Comment: this give me Error: "No member named 'cout' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'count'?"

Comment: right, you need to add #include <iostream> atop you .mm file. That's only to check if it's working though. You will want to use your own std::ostream later on. I'm updating my answer accordingly.

Comment: you are real Snip3r :) worked, can you suggest me to create MemoryStream and use it with BinaryWriter? (iam in core C#.NET programmer and my experience with Objc is 1 month)

Comment: Well MemoryStream is a .Net class, and I don't know the equivalent for C++ OpenFrameworks.. BUT you can use Monotouch to develop in C#.Net on iPhone http://xamarin.com/monotouch

Answer (score 1):

You just have to set your .m to .mm and then you can use c++.

So, from

- class.h
- class.m

to

- class.h
- class.mm

This line

```
_myBinaryWriter = new Poco::BinaryWriter(NULL, NULL);
```

creates your poco::binarywriter. The error

> No matching constructor for initialization of 'Poco::BinaryWriter'

Says that you are not creating it correctly.

You have to properly create it following these guidelines:

```
BinaryWriter(std::ostream& ostr, StreamByteOrder byteOrder = NATIVE_BYTE_ORDER);
/// Creates the BinaryWriter.

BinaryWriter(std::ostream& ostr, TextEncoding& encoding, StreamByteOrder byteOrder = NATIVE_BYTE_ORDER);
/// Creates the BinaryWriter using the given TextEncoding.
///
/// Strings will be converted from the currently set global encoding
/// (see Poco::TextEncoding::global()) to the specified encoding.
```

Comment: updated question, i did it before you tell that, but no effect, compiler Error happens.

Comment: this line _myBinaryWriter = new Poco::BinaryWriter(NULL, NULL);
creates your poco::binarywriter. the error No matching constructor for initialization of 'Poco::BinaryWriter' says that you are not creating it correctly

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your specific question but general advice.

With more recent versions of the LLVM compiler (i.e. Xcode 4.x) you can put your instance variables in the implementation, not the interface. i.e.

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate
{
    Poco::BinaryWriter *_myBinaryWriter;
}

// etc

@end
```

This means that your instance variables are now hidden from files that import the header and the header now contains no C++ code so you can import it into other Objective-C files without making them Objective-C++

Comment: sure, i know that, but i was thinking maybe error joined to Property declaration :) but anyway thanks