# iOS: example of usage Poco::BinaryReader & Poco::BinaryWriter

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, poco-libraries

Can someone show me Example of usage [Poco::BinaryReader](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/blob/master/libs/poco/include/Poco/BinaryReader.h) and [Poco::BinaryWriter](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/blob/master/libs/poco/include/Poco/BinaryWriter.h) with bynary stream on iOS 5.x -> Objective-C++ ?

Yesterday i send question about "[How to create and use C++ classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910408/ios-define-and-use-c-in-objective-c/10911383)" but its not answer on my question above.

Poco community forum and OpenFrameworks forum looks like died, so i am here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, no body wants to help.

I did it myself with God help.

> Download [OpenFrameworks](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/) and configure to your destination project;

Code sample:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Poco/MemoryStream.h"
#import "Poco/BinaryWriter.h"
#import "Poco/BinaryReader.h"

@implementation AppDelegate{
    Poco::BinaryWriter *_myBinaryWriter;
    Poco::BinaryReader *_myBinaryReader;
}

@synthesize window = _window;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = [[UIViewController new] autorelease];

    int bufferSize = 512;    
    char *_buffer = (char *)malloc(bufferSize);

    // >> WRITE BLOCK <<   
    Poco::MemoryOutputStream *outStream = new Poco::MemoryOutputStream(_buffer, bufferSize);

    _myBinaryWriter = new Poco::BinaryWriter(*outStream);
    (*_myBinaryWriter) << 1234567890;
    (*_myBinaryWriter) << (std::string)"some string";
    (*_myBinaryWriter) << 3.14f;
    delete(_myBinaryWriter);
    delete(outStream);

    // >> READ BLOCK <<   
    Poco::MemoryInputStream *inStream = new Poco::MemoryInputStream(_buffer, bufferSize);

    _myBinaryReader = new Poco::BinaryReader(*inStream);

    int i = 0;
    std::string s;
    float f = .0f;

    (*_myBinaryReader) >> i >> s >> f;
    delete(_myBinaryReader);
    delete(inStream);

    NSLog(@"ReadInt = '%i'", i);
    NSLog(@"ReadString = '%@'", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:s.c_str()]);
    NSLog(@"ReadFloat = '%f'", f);

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

have i nice day :)